Springboot object initialisation with JpaRepository
I have using Springboot to build a discord bot with database connection. Now I have having injection issue with JpaRepository when it is coming to building the EventListener.
I am having issues at jda.addEventListener(new QuestionListener()); because it is requires QuestionService to be passed in during object creation of QuestionListener, which in turn the QuestionService need QuestionRepository to be passed in. Then I can't create a QuestionRepository to be passed in because it is an interface.
Full code snippet below.
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        DiscordBot bot = new DiscordBot();
        bot.run();
    }
}

@Component
public class DiscordBot {

    public void run(){
        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("token")
                .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT)
                .build();
        jda.addEventListener(new QuestionListener()); //Issues here
    }
}

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QuestionListener extends ListenerAdapter {

    private final QuestionService questionService ;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        String string = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
        String qn;
        if (string.equalsIgnoreCase("Question!")) {
            qn = questionService.getRandomQuestion();
        }
    }
}

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QuestionService{

    private final QuestionRepository questionRepository ;

    public String getRandomQuestion() {
        // pesduo code.... 
        questionRepository.findById(with a random number);
    }
}

@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<QuestionEntity, Long> {
}

I tried playing around with @Autowired but it doesn't work.  I am feeling this might be a design issue from the very start.

How exactly @Autowired doesn't work?

Spring 101, @Autowired will only work on Spring Managed beans - meaning in any class you create with new - @Autowired won't work . Look for some beginner Spring tutorials
